# This page contains the following errors: error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I am trying to run a server locally using ngrok to use a Twilio phone number to receive calls, but when I run ngrok http 3000 and put the url it generated the error below appears.
What can it be? All the files are giving this problem.

Erro:

[image]

```
    <?php
// Create a route that will handle Twilio webhook requests, sent as an
// HTTP POST to /voice in our application
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'Curl.class.php';
require_once './utils/Utils.php';
include '/core/DigitalLockApi.class.php';

const baseUrl = 'https://digital-lock-api-node.paymobi.com.br/';

function logText($title, $content)
{
    $logfile = fopen("./log.txt", "a");
    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . $title);
    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . print_r($content, true));
    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . "-----------------------------------");
    fclose($logfile);
}

function initErrorsLog()
{
    $log_file = "errors.log";
    ini_set("log_errors", true);
    ini_set('error_log', $log_file);
}

use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

// Use the Twilio PHP SDK to build an XML response
$response = new VoiceResponse();
initErrorsLog();

if (array_key_exists('Digits', $_POST)) {
    $cpf = $_POST['Digits'];
    $cpfString = (string) $cpf;

    if(validateCPF($cpfString)) {        
        $response->redirect("./password.php?cpf=$cpf");
    } else {
        $response->redirect('./invalidCpf.php');
    }

    
} else {
    $gather = $response->gather(['numDigits' => '100', 'timeout' => '4']);

    $gather->play("https://digital-lock-api.azurewebsites.net/ura/assets/audios/insertCpf.mp3");

    // If the user doesn't enter input loop
    $response->redirect('./cpfNull.php');
}

// Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $response;
```

Comment: If you really have spaces before the `<?php` on the first line, remove them, and see if that helps.

Comment: that space is because I copied and pasted the code here. In the editor it has no such spaces

Answer (score 0):

Debugging line by line I found out that what was breaking the code was the

```
include '/core/DigitalLockApi.class.php';
```

It was not finding this import

Comment: If you use `require` instead of `include` you'll get a proper PHP error message, and stop the script, instead of just a warning. Anyway, the PHP error log could have helped you here to find the problem much sooner.